# Backbone - better understanding of templates

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, underscore.js-templating

I use backbone inside Rails. I got a very strange behaviour and I try to understand why it happens.

My model has an optional attribute `avatar_url`. I use it to generate an `img` tag. I got the following html code:

`<img src="[object HTMLInputElement]" class="avatar-bubble">`

When I looked at my code, I realize that I also have this static code:

`<input id="avatar_url" type="text" class="form-control" />`

My conclusion is that from some reason backbone takes also existing DOm objects in account when calculating the value of a given variable.

I wanted to dig inside the template parser and debug it in order to have a better idea of the login it has but couldn't find how to.
My question is what is the logic that uses backbone in order to assign a value to the template variables.

**EDIT:**
In the view I have implemented a `render` method which does the following:

```
render: function() {
  var viewData = this.model.toJSON();
  this.$el.html( this.template( viewData ) );
  return this;
}
```

Comment: Executive summary: none of the values in an Underscore template are really optional, your `toJSON` methods need to supply all of them in the objects they return; even if their value is `undefined` or `null` they still need to be there.

Comment: BTW, this is a good question even though it is a duplicate. I only knew that this was a duplicate because you found the DOM problem and I remember being puzzled about it when I answered the duplicate. I don't know if I would have been able to find the duplicate otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any Backbone "magic" to handle and render templates. The `render` method of a view is [a no-op by default](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render), and having a `template` method or property is [just a recommended convention](http://backbonejs.org/#View-template) - again, nothing implemented for you, no magic.

There are frameworks built on top of Backbone, like Marionette, which add that kind of automatic functionality. Without those, you'd have to dig into your Rails code to figure out what's going on. Because Backbone views don't actually add anything to the DOM, or parse templates, until you write the code for it.

(The only thing a Backbone view provides out of the box is a container element, [the `el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el), which is generated automatically on instantiation but not attached to the DOM).

Comment: You're right, I have just editted my question and added the missing `render` method code.